# How to add if input is empty within this code?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, if-statement, input

I'm a bit stuck on how to add in this code if the inputs are empty, to shoot an alert. Would I add another function within the first? Any hints would be appreciated!

```
function getCandidateNames() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
        if (inputs[i].getElementsByTagName("candidate")) {
            result.push(inputs[i].value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function putCandidateNames(names) {
    document.getElementById("candidateName1").innerHTML = names[0];
    document.getElementById("candidateName2").innerHTML = names[1];
    document.getElementById("candidateName3").innerHTML = names[2];
}

function candidateNames() {
    putCandidateNames(getCandidateNames());
}
```

The HTML

```
<fieldset id="candidates">
    <legend>Candidates</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="cand1">Candidate 1</label>
        <input class="candidate" id="cand1" placeholder="Candidate">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="cand2">Candidate 2</label>
        <input class="candidate" id="candName" placeholder="Candidate">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="cand3">Candidate 3</label>
        <input class="candidate" id="candName" placeholder="Candidate">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: `inputs[i].getElementsByTagName("candidate")` is completely wrong here you should use `getElementsByClassName("candidate")` instead and don't use the same id `id="candName"` for multiple elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many problems in your code that needs to be fixed:

- You can't use the same id `id="candName"` for multiple elements in the page.
- This code `inputs[i].getElementsByTagName("candidate")` is completely wrong here you should use `getElementsByClassName("candidate")` instead, because you don't have `candidate` tags you used them as classes.
- And instead of getting the `inputs` nodeList then iterate over it with `inputs[i].getElementsByTagName("candidate")` you can just use `document.getElementsByClassName("candidate")`.

This is how should be your code:

```
function getCandidateNames() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("candidate");
  var result = [];
  if (Array.prototype.some.call(inputs, function(input) {
      return input.value === "";
    })) {
    alert("Inputs should not be empty!!!");
    return false;
  }
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
    result.push(input.value);
  });
  return result;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function getCandidateNames() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("candidate");
  var result = [];
  if (Array.prototype.some.call(inputs, function(input) {
      return input.value === "";
    })) {
    alert("Inputs should not be empty!!!");
    return false;
  }
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
    result.push(input.value);
  });
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="candidates">
  <legend>Candidates</legend>
  <div>
    <label for="cand1">Candidate 1</label>
    <input class="candidate" id="cand1" placeholder="Candidate">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="cand2">Candidate 2</label>
    <input class="candidate" id="candName" placeholder="Candidate">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="cand3">Candidate 3</label>
    <input class="candidate" id="candName2" placeholder="Candidate">
  </div>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="getCandidateNames()">Validate</button>
```

**Note:**

Note the use of `Array.prototype.forEach.call` and `Array.prototype.some.call`, which are used to loop over the `nodeList` borrowing JavaScript `Array` built-in functions.

---

### Alternative:

This is an alternative using simple syntax:

```
function getCandidateNames() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("candidate");
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].value !== "") {
      result.push(inputs[i].value);
    } else {
      alert("Inputs can't be empty !!!");
      return false;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function getCandidateNames() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("candidate");
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].value !== "") {
      result.push(inputs[i].value);
    } else {
      alert("Inputs can't be empty !!!");
      return false;
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="candidates">
  <legend>Candidates</legend>
  <div>
    <label for="cand1">Candidate 1</label>
    <input class="candidate" id="cand1" placeholder="Candidate">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="cand2">Candidate 2</label>
    <input class="candidate" id="candName" placeholder="Candidate">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="cand3">Candidate 3</label>
    <input class="candidate" id="candName2" placeholder="Candidate">
  </div>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="getCandidateNames()">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Why don't you just write `inputs.forEach(...)` and `inputs.some(...)` instead?

Comment: @YongQuan because `inputs` is a`nodeList` and not an actual `array`, so we can't call these functions directtly on it, so we just borrowed them :)

Comment: I see. Totally overlooked the data as HTMLCollection part. Thanks!

Comment: @chsdk Is there anyway to not use "Array.prototype.forEach.call"? As in I'm trying to learn the language in a simplified way :/

Comment: @BeckyT Yes of course there's, I m updating my answer.

Comment: @chsdk Thank you so much!! I can't appreciate and thank you enough for your help :)